# Simple discounting rate question and finding unknown time:

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

[image]

The thing is to solve for n.

This is how far I got:
$FV=PV(1-d)^{-t}$

So, $1000(1-0.05)^{-10} + 2000(1-0.05)^{-5}= 1000(1-0.1)^{-(10-n)}+2000(1-0.1)^{-(10-2n)}$

$\Longrightarrow\;\; 2584.71=1000(0.9)^{-(10-n)}+2000(0.9)^{-(10-2n)}$

$\Longrightarrow\;\; 2.58471= (0.9)^{-10}(0.9)^n + 2(0.9)^{-10}(0.9)^{2n}$

$\Longrightarrow\;\; 2.58471=2.87(0.9)^n+5.74(0.9)^{2n}$

let $X=0.9^n$
we get: $5.74X^2+2.87X-2.58471$
Solve for $X=0.47$

$\Longrightarrow\;\; 0.47=0.9^n$
then applied $\ln$ to both sides and got $n=7$.

Is this correct?!

Comment: Hi Mi-lee.  You might be able to attract more (helpful) answers if you TeXify your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Fund 1: discount $d=5\%$, Fund 2: interest $i=10\%$.

$$
\frac{1000}{(1-d)^{10}}+\frac{2000}{(1-d)^{5}}=1000(1+i)^{10-n}+2000(1+i)^{10-2n}\tag 1
$$

$$
4,254.89=\underbrace{1000(1.1)^{10}}_{2,593.74}\left(1.1^{-n}+2\times 1.1^{-2n}\right)\tag 2
$$
Putting $x=1.1^{-n}$ and $a=\frac{4,254.89}{2,593.74}=1.64$ the $(2)$ becomes
$$
x+2x^2=a \tag 3
$$
and solving equation $(3)$ we find the roots
$$
x_{1,2} = \frac{\pm\sqrt{8 a+1}-1}{4} \quad\Longrightarrow x_1=-1.18941,\;x_2= 0.689415
$$
Discarding the negative solution we have $1.1^{-n}=0.689415$ and then $-n\log (1.1)=\log{0.689415}$, that is

> $$
> n=3.9
> $$